# How to write unit test for switch case using jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, switch-statement, jasmine

below is my code

```
var s=function(){
return 'API CALL';//Through some API call i am getting and integer value
};

switch(s()){
case 0: store.p1="Some Text"; break;
case 1: store.p1="Some Other Text"; break;
case 2: store.p1="Another Text"; break;
}
```

In the above function i am firing API call,which returns an integer value(0,1,2) and storing it in 's', i wanted to write unit test using jasmine..., could anyone please help how to write test case?!

Note: 'store' is global variable and p1 is a another variable in 'store' where i want to store the value of 's'.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you make this `switch statement` a `function` that takes a `parameter` and returns a message based on the parameter. This way the unit test will be easier because you can unit test the function.

```
function getValueStoredMessage(integer) {
 return 'value ' + integer + ' stored';
}
```

and you can call it like this:

```
store.p1 = getValueStoredMessage(valueFromApi);
```

I personally haven't written many unit tests, but I imagine a function would be easier than a switch?

Comment: but i have different text to be returned based on the case..., for example if the returned value is 0 then set store.p1="abcd", vice versa for return values 1 and 2. Sorry it was my bad i would've written in code that store.p1="some text" when case 0 is selected, store.p1="some other text" when case 1 is selected and store.p1="another text" when case 2 is selected.

Answer (score 0):

To correctly test your API function you will need to mock it out and have it fake the return value. There are many ways to do this, and some of it will depend on how your API works (angular http, service, promise, etc).

Take a look at jasmine spys. They will probably be the easiest if it will work for your situation. Something along the lines of:

```
spyOn(APIObject, "APIMethod").and.returnValue(1);  
expect(store.p1).toBe(value 1 stored);
```

If you don't have an mock object to spyOn you can create one using `createSpy` and it will work the same way.

Comment: ktharsis thank you for your reply..., i have tried your spyOn and expect but it says Error: Expected undefined to be 'value 1 stored'. I have recognised that jasmine is unable to find store.p1 variable... it seems like my spec file is not referring to javascript file where my store.p1 is defined, m i right? And i have edited the question value 1 stored to 'Some Text' and vice versa..

Comment: You will need to provide more of your code for us to be able to help, especially the test portion which you are having troubles with. If you add code/try new things be sure to update the question instead of just adding comments to each answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the cases (just like in yours) using map is a better choice than using switch.

```
function f(){
    var myInteger = syncApiCallReturnsInteger();
    var map = {
        0: "Some Text",
        1: "Some Other Text",
        2: "Another Text"
    };
    store.p1 = map[myInteger];
}
```

If you want to test this, you have to mock out the syncApiCallReturnsInteger(). In order to do that it must be injectable. The store must be injectable as well, so you can check it's changes.

```
function f(syncApiCallReturnsInteger, store){
    var myInteger = syncApiCallReturnsInteger();
    var map = {
        0: "Some Text",
        1: "Some Other Text",
        2: "Another Text"
    };
    store.p1 = map[myInteger];
}
```

The test:

```
describe("blah", function() {
    it("f sets store.p1", function() {
        var fixture2expectation = {
            0: "Some Text",
            1: "Some Other Text",
            2: "Another Text"
        };

        for (var fixtureString in fixture2expectation){
            var fixture = parseInt(fixtureString);
            var expectation = fixture2expectation[fixture];
            var mockApiCall = function (){return fixture;};
            var mockStore = {};
            f(mockApiCall, mockStore);
            expect(mockStore.p1).toBe(expectation);
        }
    });
});
```

If you don't inject the dependencies properly, then the only thing you can do is using and overriding globals, which is generally a bad idea, because there will be variable name collisions later when your project grows.

Answer (score 0):

In simplest terms you don't test a switch.

A switch, just like if, else, where, when and other such things are language construct, so needs no testing.  Testing a portion of your code that deals with flow control, you write different test for each outcome of the flow.

This means a separate suite for each option.

`function rockPaperScisors(){
        ... 
        // switch statement for the return value
    }`

```
describe('rock paper scissors caller', function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
        var throw;
    });

    it("should return rock when 1 is entered", function(){
        throw = 1;
        expect(throw).toEqual('rock');
    });

    it("should return paper when 2 is entered", function(){
        throw = 2;
        expect(throw).toEqual('paper');
    });

    it("should return scissor when 3 is entered", function(){
        throw = 3;
        expect(throw).toEqual('scisor');
    });
});
```